# why QTableWidget does not refresh after closing tab in pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

the below example is my problem which can not figure it out! i appreciate if anyone can help on this problem. i have set of data which in this example i am reading from csv file. in next step i am filling my QTableWidget with the data. The problem is when i change data and close the tab and open it, the data does not refresh.
here is my sample code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, QTabWidget, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 400)

        self.setup_ui()
        self.show()

    def setup_ui(self):
        # toolbar
        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Tool Bar')
        self.test_btn = QAction('Test', self)
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.test_btn)
        self.test_btn.triggered.connect(self.load_data)

        # tab
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tab_test = QWidget()
        self.tabs.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.tabs.tabCloseRequested.connect(lambda tab_index: self.tabs.removeTab(tab_index))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)

    def load_data(self):
        # get data
        data = []
        with open('test_data.csv', 'r') as f:
            header = next(f).replace('\n', '').split(',')
            for line in f:
                data.append(line.replace('\n', '').split(','))
        print(data)

        # table and button widget
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab_test, 'Test')
        self.table = QTableWidget()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.tab_test.setLayout(self.layout)

        # fill headers
        self.table.setColumnCount(len(header))
        for i, field_name in enumerate(header):
            self.table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(i, QTableWidgetItem(field_name))

        # fill data
        for row, row_data in enumerate(data):
            self.table.insertRow(row)
            for col, data in enumerate(row_data):
                self.table.setItem(row, col, QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))


def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    ui = MainWindow()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and this is the sample data for `test_data.csv`:

```
col_1,col_2
1,2
10,20
100,200
```

before updating data:

[image]

but after updating 100 to 1000 and 200 to 2000 in csv file then closing tab and opening it, the data has been updated but the items of table not!

[image]

[image]

what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning a single `QWidget` instance at `MainWindow.setup_ui`, right here:

> ```
> def setup_ui(self):
>     # toolbar
>     self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Tool Bar')
>     self.test_btn = QAction('Test', self)
>     # .
>     # .
>
>     # tab
>     self.tabs = QTabWidget() # <--
>     # .
>     # .
>     # .
>     self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)
> ```

This means that you're always adding the same `QWidget` over and over to the `QTabWidget`. So, when you call `MainWindow.load_data`, this function call `self.tabs.addTab(tab_test, 'Test')` does nothing, because the widget is already present on the table widget.

What you should do, is to create a new `QWidget` inside `MainWindow.load_data`, just like this:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, QTabWidget, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 400)

        self.setup_ui()
        self.show()

    def setup_ui(self):
        # toolbar
        toolbar = self.addToolBar('Tool Bar')
        test_btn = QAction('Test', self)
        toolbar.addAction(test_btn)
        test_btn.triggered.connect(self.load_data)

        # tab
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tabs.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.tabs.tabCloseRequested.connect(lambda tab_index: self.tabs.removeTab(tab_index))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)

    def load_data(self):
        # get data
        data = []
        with open('test_data.csv', 'r') as f:
            header = next(f).replace('\n', '').split(',')
            for line in f:
                data.append(line.replace('\n', '').split(','))
        print(data)

        # table and button widget
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        tab_test = QWidget()               ## MOVED THIS LINE FROM setup_ui
        self.tabs.addTab(tab_test, 'Test')
        table = QTableWidget()
        layout.addWidget(table)
        tab_test.setLayout(layout)

        # fill headers
        table.setColumnCount(len(header))
        for i, field_name in enumerate(header):
            table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(i, QTableWidgetItem(field_name))

        # fill data
        for row, row_data in enumerate(data):
            table.insertRow(row)
            for col, data in enumerate(row_data):
                table.setItem(row, col, QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))


def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    ui = MainWindow()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Note that I used local variables on `setup_ui` and `load_data` scopes. As most variables in there are not being used in other `MainWindow` methods, it's not needed to store them to `self`, unlike `self.tabs`. Also, as every tab should be independent of each other, it's not a good thing to overwrite the `self.test_tab` variable, unless you do need to store only the last added tab.

Comment: thanks a lot, yeah you are right about self... for this example i copied most of variables from bigger project so that's why i missed to remvoe them but as you mentioned i will check and delete unnecessary selfs. About overwriting no, i am not at least i think i am not! my logic is "if tab is opened do nothing and if it is closed create all items and get newest data from db" i think it was better and neater than creating all objects at initializing step. again thanks

Comment: @CarlHR Note that the actual issue is not that the tab already exists, but that the OP is attempting to set *again* the layout with a *new* table, but since it's not possible to set a layout on a widget that already has one, the new table is never shown.

Comment: @RahmanTavakoli Yes, you're overwriting, if not the tab, at least its contents. Since there will always exist one widget (the one added as tab and containing the table), then you should do that only once (possibly in the `__init__`), then the function will just add the tab with the *existing* widget and update the *existing* table; also note that, in your case, you should use `setRowCount()` and before the for loop, then remove `insertRow()` and just use `setItem()` as you already do. Finally, if you only have the table in the tab, `tab_test` is useless: `self.tabs.addTab(self.table, 'Test')`.